# Kotlin Application with Gradle application plugin

Tags: gradle, jvm, kotlin, build.gradle

I am trying to create a simple HelloWorld application using `kotlin`, `gradle`, and the gradle `application` plugin. When I run it with the below setup I get the following error:

```
Error: Main method is not static in class com.petarkolaric.helloworld.Main, please define the main method as:
public static void main(String[] args)
```

My `build.gradle`:

```
group 'helloworld'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.0'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = "com.petarkolaric.helloworld.Main"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

My `src/main/kotlin/com/petarkolaric/helloworld/Main.kt`:

```
package com.petarkolaric.helloworld

class Main {

    fun main(args : Array<String>) {
        println("Hello, World!")
    }
}
```

According to [this blog post](http://zweifisch.github.io/kotlin-with-gradle.html#sec-3-2) I should be able to use the application plugin this way.

What do I need to change to allow the `application` plugin to run my main function when I run `gradle run`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As the error says, your main method is not static. You have the following options:

1) Put the main into the `companion object` and make it `JvmStatic`

```
class Main {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun main(args : Array<String>) {
            println("Hello, World!")
        }
    }
}
```

2) Change your `class` to `object` - than you more or less have a singleton `class` and make it `JvmStatic`

```
object Main {
    @JvmStatic
    fun main(args : Array<String>) {
        println("Hello, World!")
    }
}
```

3) Place the main outside the class

```
fun main(args : Array<String>) {
    println("Hello, World!")
}
class Main {
}
```

Comment: Options 1 and 2 work, but I think option 3 is what I'd prefer. When I try it, however, it appears that gradle can no longer find the main method:

`Error: Main method not found in class com.petarkolaric.helloworld.Main, please define the main method as:
public static void main(String[] args)`

Do you have any idea why this is?

Comment: Because the class name changes: it will be `MainKt` if your file is called `Main.kt`.

Comment: I see - top level functions are compiled into their own class which you need to reference from the build.gradle. Thanks!

Comment: For your example 3) it is worth mentioning that you can omit the `class Main {}` part and what Alexey said of course.