# Can't run generated JAR file with Gradle and Kotlin

Tags: java, gradle, jar, kotlin

I have a project configured with Gradle and Kotlin. It's a command line utility and I would like to be able to run the generated jar from my terminal. However I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics
    at com.autentia.impt.MainKt.main(Main.kt)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 1 more
```

My gradle configuration is as follows:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.20'
    ext.junit_platform_version = '1.0.1'
    ext.junit_version = '5.0.0'
    ext.moshi_version = '1.5.0'
    ext.jna_version = '4.5.0'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.junit.platform:junit-platform-gradle-plugin:$junit_platform_version"
    }
}

version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'org.junit.platform.gradle.plugin'

mainClassName = 'com.autentia.impt.MainKt'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect"
    implementation "com.squareup.moshi:moshi:$moshi_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:$moshi_version"
    implementation "net.java.dev.jna:jna:$jna_version"
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:$junit_version")
    testRuntime("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:$junit_version")
}

sourceSets {
    main.kotlin.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.4.1'
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes "Main-Class": mainClassName
    }

    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}

compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

The command I use to generate the jar is `./gradlew clean build` and the command I use to run the jar is `java -jar build/libs/impt-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`.

I've tried following the [official docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html) and also I've tried with these resources: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33738304/configuring-gradle-with-kotlin?noredirect=1&lq=1), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26469365/building-a-self-executable-jar-with-gradle-and-kotlin) and [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47766179/kotlin-application-with-gradle-application-plugin) without any luck.

Comment: it seems you don't have certain dependencies on the classpath. Is it possible you had these dependencies on the path of your IDE, instead of on that of your machine itself?

Comment: Same problem! Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just change `implementation` configurations to `compile`. (At least for kotlin-stdlib)

The `compile` configuration is deprecated and should be replaced by `implementation` or `api` in Gradle plugin for Android, however for `kotlin-gradle-plugin`, I think you still need *compile*.

Answer (score -1):

Alright I had the same problem and finally figured this out:

My main class name was `Main.kt` and this is what I had in my `build.gradle` file when I was getting the same error:

```
jar {
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Class-Path': configurations.compile.collect { it.getName() }.join(' '),
                'Main-Class': "play.Main"
        )
    }
}
```

Although I noticed when I create the `jar` artifact in Intellij, it uses `play.MainKt` as my `Main-Class` name (yeah, weird naming convention), then I changed my `build.gradle` file to this:

```
jar {
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Class-Path': configurations.compile.collect { it.getName() }.join(' '),
                'Main-Class': "play.MainKt"
        )
    }
}
```

and now I am not getting that error.